# SPAM notification/warning in postfix mail.log if email classifed as SPAM by DSPAM

Tags: postfix, log-files, dspam

currently in my setup i have postfix, dspam and clamav configured. Everything works perfectly. The only thing is when dspam detected an email as SPAM mail, in postfix mail.log there
is no such message/warn/notification about it, the only thing that shows is (delivered
via dspam service).

and i need to tail/open dspam system.log in order to know that the email actually been
classfied/tagged as spam by dspam.

is there any way that i can automatically add this infomation in postfix mail.log?

Answer (score 1):

Get dspam to write a message to the syslog mail facility; that'll drop it into mail.log.

Answer (score 1):

the dspam system.log file contains information for the web UI - the closest you can get with syslog information AFAIK is to use the TrackSources parameter in dspam.conf:

TrackSources spam nonspam

(spam|nonspam|virus) are supported in newer versions I believe.

...

Feb 26 03:47:00  dspam[]: spam detected from 
Feb 26 03:47:22  dspam[]: innocent message from